# Can you add a variable in a branch.io link's fallback URL?

Tags: branch.io

I would like to have the fallback URL for my branch.io app to include data from the link that was redirected to it.  For example, say someone clicks a branch.io link for my app like this:

https://example.app.link/12345

And 12345 actually has NOT been registered as a link in my branch.io app.  Ideally I would like that to route to:

https://mywebsite.com/somepath/12345

In other words, I want the unique identifier on the invalid branch link to be appended to my fallback URL.

Is this possible??  Documentation is pretty sparse with what happens to invalid branch links.

Answer (score 3):

Jackie from Branch here.
You can pass off any key-value pair by appending it to a valid Branch link.
For example, I created a link (https://jackie.app.link/e/y1v9OX2EGO/) with the following link data:

```
{
  "branch_key": "my_live_key",
  "data": {
  "$desktop_url": "https://www.google.com/"
  }
}
```

If I append a key-value pair to the link `https://jackie.app.link/e/y1v9OX2EGO/?path=123`, this will change the desktop URL from `https://www.google.com/?_branch_match_id=547473905295523265` to `https://www.google.com/?path=123&_branch_match_id=547473905295523265`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jackie.  I'm actually asking about the case where it's NOT a valid branch link and thus branch redirects to the fallback link.  Is there a way to configure that fallback link in the dashboard such that it appends the id (even though invalid) to the fallback link?